Google Cloud Function doesn't get along with golang's embed files
If I use golang's embed files like this
//go:embed creds/a.json
var aCredentialsFile []byte

//go:embed creds/b.json
var bCredentialsFile []byte

// ...

Sometimes when deploying I get errors like this
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: internal/depinj/creds.go:35:12: pattern creds/a.json: no matching files found. For more details see the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=....

The file's location and it's path relative to the go file hasn't changed since the last deploy. It just "breaks on its own".
The workaround is to rename every file and their respective embed comment. For example, appending a "2" at the end of the file name
//go:embed creds/a2.json
var aCredentialsFile []byte

//go:embed creds/b2.json
var bCredentialsFile []byte

// ...

This forces a "reload of something", and the deploy works, until it breaks again after some time.
Is this a known bug? Is there a way to avoid having to rename every embed file?
